# 'ip route get' in Java

Tags: java, networking, routes

How can I know whether an IP address is theoretically accessible? I would want the Java code to behave just like the following Linux invocation:

```
# ip route get 192.168.36.5
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
```

where no timeout parameter is accepted because it doesn't actually try to connect to the IP address. It just determines if the address is reachable according to the system's routing table.

Comment: You don't want to invoke command line tools from Java? Because you can do the exact same command, get the output and parse it in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java you can execute shell comands using the exec() method.
See if the code below helps:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ip route get 192.168.36.5");
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be some Java class that I could use so that I wouldn't have to resort to that kind of thing.

Comment: No one else offered any solutions so I'll accept this answer